# Analytical solution for the characteristic impedance along vertical wire over PEC ground plane (at given point h)?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, wire, transmission-line, characteristic-impedance

For the purpose of TL transformer simulation I need a solution for the characteristic impedance of vertical wire, with radius a, at the infinitesimally short segment - not point, at the height h above perfect ground.

For horizontal wire over (PEC) ground, we have analytical solution:

$$Z_o' = (Z_{fs}/2\pi) \times a\cosh(h/a)$$

That solution, derived from the characteristic inductance and capacitance of the wire against its mirror image, works well even for slightly sloped wire (if we make very short segments).

I am not sure, does that equation apply anymore for angles approaching vertical and finally vertical wire over PEC ground? Most of theoretical framework is based on the mirror image. Despite best efforts to find a solution for the vertical wire, I couldn't find any.

Does it exist? My math level is far below needed to solve it by hand.

I made some research toward evaluation/approximation of the specific inductance and capacitance (\$L' C'\$) along short monopole (vertical wire above PEC ground). If one could derive such evaluation, we can get specific impedance from relation \$Z_o'= \sqrt{L'/C'}\$. Unfortunately, no explicit solution exists. The closest solution for capacitance could be derived from this research on: [Approximate Capacitance of Short Thick Monopoles...](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA302235.pdf)
So far I could not find any research on specific inductance, except Grover's general solutions for wire self inductance in free space from: [FORMULAS AND TABLES FOR THE CALCULATION OF MUTUAL AND SELF-INDUCTANCE](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/bulletin/08/nbsbulletinv8n1p1_A2b.pdf)

Comment: A point floating above earth can be assumed to be open circuit relative to Zo

Comment: Look at that "point" as infinitesimally short segment of the wire, which have its characteristic inductance and capacitance, therefor it has characteristic impedance (sqrt(L'/C'))

Comment: Yes C will be 0 for a point

Comment: Again, it is not a point, just arbitrary short segment of the wire.

Comment: To avoid further confusion I edited original question. And we are talking about C' and L', not C and L.

Comment: When Zo is so short and just a point relative to the wavelength , it is meaningless and thus considered floating like discrete values of C and leakage R

Comment: What do you mean when you say the wire is "vertical"? A diagram might help make the question more clear.

Comment: Vertical to the ground plane, like monopole, but we are looking for the instant impedance along that wire, not at the feed point.

Comment: Added research toward getting specific inductance and capacitance along the wire.